# cómo hacer que un grafico no cambie su tamaño en excel con Python, xlsxwriter y pandas

Tags: python, pandas

he estado trabajando sobre un pequeño algoritmo con Pandas y he logrado algunos avances. Hasta ahora me he atorado con 2 cosas. La primera es la siguiente:

- Al crear el nuevo archivo de excel con la data y el gráfico, la data lleva un filtro y al elegir algún elemento, el gráfico cambia su tamaño. He leído la documentación y no encuentro la propiedad para impedir que cambie su tamaño conforme se manipulen los filtros como si se tratara de un excel hecho a mano.
- Lo Segundo es que tengo un constructor para formatear la data y tal cual la documentación está hecho pero parece que algo estoy haciendo mal que no lo hace el código como yo lo quiero.

  ```py
  format1 = workbook.add_format({"border": 0
                             , "align" : "Left"
                             , "valign" : "vcenter"
                             , "bold" : 0})

  format2 = workbook.add_format({"border": 0
                             , "align" : "center"
                             , "valign" : "vcenter"
                             , "bold" : 0})

  worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40.29, format1)
  worksheet.set_column('B:C', 22.86, format2)
  ```

hasta esta parte, la clumna A:A mantiene el formato de dataframe y no se formatea como quiero que lo haga el format1

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede apoyar con algún comentario sobre lo que debo hacer. Les agradezco a todos.
Dejo aquí parte del código para que pueda ser visualizado

Comment: Hola. El código, los logs y todo lo demás van siempre como texto. Replicar desde una imagen oculta errores o hace que otros cometan errores al transcribir. Por favor, edita tus aportes y procura usar texto.

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya lo edité

Answer (score 0):

Actualización.
He logrado hacer la primera duda. Comparto el codigo para quién lo necesite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, el código debe ir como texto por favor y si quieres agregar más detalles a tu pregunta recuerda que siempre puedes [Editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/602199/edit). ;)

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo edite. Gracias por la observación.